# Does OkHttp3 auto retry POST request by default

Tags: httpurlconnection, okhttp

The concern is about a bill system.

When the client(Android or PC) use `okhttp3` to send a `POST` or `PUT` request, the bill server may get the request and insert a bill record in database but will response within a really long period, so the client does not manage to receive a valid(in-time) response. The point is at this circumstance, will `okhttp3` re-send the request?

This is very important because if it retries, there will be duplicated records in database without comparing the old bill records.

The reason I doubt this is that the `OkHttpClient.Builder` has a method called `retryOnConnectionFailure`, how will this affect the post request behavior? As the method name is about connection.

Also the same question about the retry behavior of `HttpURLConnection`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refer to this issue [#2394](https://github.com/square/okhttp/issues/2394) in github. It seems that `okhttp` **3.2** DOES have this retry issue. And in **3.3** version, this behavior changes to
**Don't recover if we encounter a read timeout after sending the request, but do recover if we encounter a timeout building a connection.**